# Rails + React App Pages Require Reload To Render React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rendering, reload, webpacker

I created a new Rails + React app using `rails new exampleapp --webpack=react`. On my home page, I have a header in `html.erb`, and some react jsx being rendered using `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'reactfilename' %>`.

When I click on a link to my home page, such as `<li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>`, only the header is rendered. It is only till I reload the page that my react component is shown.

I am running both `rails s` and `./bin/webpack-dev-server` to start my application. The same problem is occurring on my Heroku web server. in which I have the following setup:

Procfile:
`web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -b 0.0.0.0`

Procfile.dev: 
`web: ./bin/rails server
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server`

Is this the expected behaviour of a React + Rails app, or is there a problem in my configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this issue has something to do with turbolinks background optimization. One workaround is to cause a complete refresh of the page by setting turbolinks to false:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

With newer versions of turbolinks:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, data: { turbo: false } %>
```

Comment: For newer versions of Rails with Turbo (previously Turbo Links), use `data: { turbo: false } `

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are loading you component after `turbolink:load` event

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  let container = document.getElementById('react-order')
  if (!container) return

  ReactDOM.render(
    <OrderForm />,
  container)
})
```

Comment: Should be `turbol:load` now.